# How to use a Chat script on a LAN?

Tags: python, sockets, chat, lan

I want to use my chat program on my home network. The code i have runs successfully on my localhost.
I want to communicate with a system on my home network and runs the client script.
For running it on localhost, the server is declared as 'localhost'.

- What address do i need to use for using it on LAN?
- How does my program structure needs to change to accomodate for the task?

The code for the server is as follows:

```
import select
import socket
import sys
import argparse

class ChatServer():
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.clients = [] #Keep a tab of all the connected clients
    #Initialise the server socket
    self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    self.server.bind((self.host, self.port))
    self.server.listen(BACKLOG)
    print "Server listening on port %s" %self.port

    self.inputs = [self.server, sys.stdin] #Keeps a tab of all the incoming connections
    self.outputs = [] #Keep a tab of all the sockets to which we need to send data

def run(self):
    running =  True
    while running:
        try:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(self.inputs, self.outputs, self.outputs)
        except socket.error, e:
            break

        for sock in readable:
            if sock == self.server:
                #If the readable socket is server then we need to accept connections and receive messages and broadcast them
                client, address = sock.accept() #client contains the socket information and address contains the address information of the client
                print 'Chat server got connected to client %s:%s ' %(address[0],address[1])
                self.clients.append((client, address))
                self.inputs.append(client)
                msg = 'Connected new client %d at %s:%s '%(len(self.clients),address[0],address[1])
                for s in self.outputs:
                    s.sendall(msg)
                self.outputs.append(client)
            elif sock == sys.stdin:
                junk = sys.stdin.readline()
                running =  False
            else:
                #All the clients that have been connected to the server
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(4096)
                    if data:
                        msg = 'Client %s:%s says : %s ' %(address[0],address[1],data)
                        for s in self.outputs:
                            s.sendall(msg)
                except socket.error , e:
                    self.inputs.remove(sock)
                    self.outputs.remove(sock)

    self.server.close()
```

The Code for the Client is as follows:

```
class ChatClient():
def __init__(self,name,port, host = SERVER_HOST):
    self.name = name
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.connected = False
    try:
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        print 'Client connected to Server at port : %s' %self.port
        self.connected = True
    except socket.error,e:
        print 'Failed to connect to socket server @port: %s' %self.port

def run(self):
    while self.connected:
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([0,self.sock],[],[])
        for sock in readable:
            if sock == 0:
                data = sys.stdin.readline()
                if data:
                    self.sock.sendall(data)
            elif sock == self.sock:
                data = self.sock.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    sys.stdout.write(data + '\n')
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                else:
                    print 'Shutting Down'
                    self.connected = False
                    break
```

The Script that initiates the Server and the Client is as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Chat Server')
parser.add_argument('--name',action = 'store', dest = 'name',required = True)
parser.add_argument('--port', action = 'store', type = int, dest = 'port',required = True)
givenArgs = parser.parse_args()
name = givenArgs.name
port = givenArgs.port

if name == 'server':
    server = ChatServer(SERVER_HOST, port)
    server.run()
else:
    client = ChatClient(name,port)
    client.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `ifconfig` (on Unix and Mac OS) or `ipconfig` (on Windows) in the command line on both client and server machines. Then try to realise which of the listed interfaces is your LAN. My suggestion is that such interfaces most probably will be in `192.168.x.x` network. After that use this two addresses in your client and server scripts correspondingly.

Comment: Thank you. I am now able to communicate between multiple systems on my home network. I only needed to  find the IP address for the machine on which server code runs.